# Edit doesn't update database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to edit some informations saved at my database.

So from readAllNew.html I am calling edit button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">

        <tr>
        <th>Naslov</th>
        <th>Datum</th>
        <th>Autor</th>
        <th>Mail</th>
        </tr>
        {% for x in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{x.naslov}}</td>
        <td>{{x.datumObjave}}</td>
        <td>{{x.autor}}</td>
        <td>{{x.email}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'delete' x.id %}">delete</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'edit' x.id %}">edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

From there this URL is calling (urls.py):

```
url(r'^app_1/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/edit/$',views.edit, name = 'edit'),
```

My views.py looks like:

```
def edit(request, id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Clanak, id = id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ClanakForma(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save(commit=False)
            data.naslov = request.user
            data.datumObjave = request.user
            data.autor = request.user
            data.email = request.user
            return redirect('readAllNew.html')
    else:
        form = ClanakForma(instance=data)
        template = 'edit.html'
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, template, context)
```

My models.py

```
class Clanak(models.Model):
    naslov = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=120)
    datumObjave = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    autor = models.CharField(null=False, blank=True, max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=75, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.naslov) + ', ' + str(self.datumObjave) + ', ' + str(self.autor)
```

My forms.py:

```
class ClanakForma(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Clanak
        fields = '__all__'
```

And my "edit.html":

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So my view should call "edit.html" and it does. I can see fields with values inside. When I change something and click "SUBMIT" I am redirected to readAllNew.html but database is not updated.

----- UPDATE -----

If I add "data.save()" and remove lines:

```
    data.naslov = request.user
    data.datumObjave = request.user
    data.autor = request.user
    data.email = request.user
```

It does not edit nothing but it add new line to table.
Same happen if I leave it without "data.save()" and those lines but change "Commit" to "False.

Comment: add `data.save()` before `redirect`

Comment: @Gasanov - Please check update section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating new model instance using form, instead of editing existing. Change your view to:

```py
def edit(request, id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Clanak, id = id)
    form = ClanakForma(request.POST or None, instance=data)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('readAllNew.html')
    template = 'edit.html'
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, template, context)
```

There were also some issues with your view, like in case form is invalid, you will not return any response to user.

Answer (score 0):

add **data.save()** before redirect as stated by @Gasanov .
Moreover , your model fields have a separate datatype and you are trying to update your model fields as **request.user**.
Either , use solution stated by @Gasanov or you can just maintain the datatypes while assigning .

You updated question : While initializing your form with the post data use

```
form = ClanakForma(request.POST, instance=data)
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method